Decrypt a text with a given key if in the encryption if was sorted alphabetically
My task is regarding transposition cipher, but with added element of sorting the columns of the matrix alphabetically using sorted() function.
For example, given the text to encrypt "Flamingo_is_a_bird" using the cipher key "Banner", the process of encrypting goes like this:
|     B    |     A    |     N    |     N    |     E    |     R    | <== KEY
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     F    |     L    |     A    |     M    |     I    |     N    |
|     G    |     O    |     _    |     I    |     S    |     _    |
|     A    |     _    |     B    |     I    |     R    |     D    |

Key is then sorted alphabetically, and each column moves accordingly. Turns into:
|     A    |     B    |     E    |     N    |     N    |     R    | <== SORTED KEY ALPHABETICALLY
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|     L    |     F    |     I    |     A    |     M    |     N    |
|     O    |     G    |     S    |     _    |     I    |     _    |
|     _    |     A    |     R    |     B    |     I    |     D    |

And then the final cipher text is read by column from left to right, top to bottom. Turns into:
LO_FGAISRA_BMIIN_D

Given the original cipher key, how can I revert back the columns to the original position, preferably using methods like sorted(), and without saving the key somewhere in the code or the computer (like a real encryption/decryption)?
This is my encrypting code. (number_of_columns is len(cipher_key)):
cipher_key_order = sorted(range(len(cipher_key)) , key=lambda alphabet: cipher_key[alphabet])
    i = 0
    encrypted_matrix = [[" " for column in range(0, number_of_columns)] for row in range(0, number_of_rows)]
    for col in range(number_of_columns):
        for row in range(number_of_rows):
            encrypted_matrix[row][col] = original_matrix[row][cipher_key_order[i]]
        i += 1


This will be somewhat tricky since BANNER has two Ns, and you'd need to keep track of which column was associated with which N to begin with. Doable, though!

... Okay, in fact, the result is ambiguous since the key has non-unique characters, and LO_FGAISRA_BMIIN_D can't store which order the key's Ns were in originally...

You could only get a list of possible starting positions (in this case, 2 possibilities).

Hey thanks all for the replies
In the end I used this:
decipher_key_order = sorted(range(len(cipher_key)), key=lambda alphabet: cipher_key[alphabet])
i = 0
decrypted_matrix = [[" " for column in range(0, number_of_columns)] for row in range(0, number_of_rows)]
for col in range(number_of_columns):
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        decrypted_matrix[row][decipher_key_order[i]] = original_matrix[row][col]
    i += 1

This is my final code. Sorry if things are not ultra efficient, I'm new to coding :)
def encrypt(input_text, cipher_key, number_of_rows, input_matrix, output_matrix, cipher_key_alphabet_order):
    
    # Turning string into matrix
    character = 0
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
            input_matrix[row][column] = input_text[character]
            character += 1
    
    # Encryption
    character = 0
    for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
        for row in range (number_of_rows):
            output_matrix[row][column] = input_matrix[row][cipher_key_alphabet_order[character]]
        character += 1
    
    # Turning matrix into string
    final_text = ""
    for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
        for row in range(number_of_rows):
            final_text += output_matrix[row][column]
    
    return final_text
    
    
def decrypt(input_text, cipher_key, number_of_rows, input_matrix, output_matrix, cipher_key_alphabet_order):
    
    # Turning string into matrix
    character = 0
    for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
        for row in range(number_of_rows):
            input_matrix[row][column] = input_text[character]
            character += 1

    # Decryption
    character = 0
    for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
        for row in range(number_of_rows):
            output_matrix[row][cipher_key_alphabet_order[character]] = input_matrix[row][column]
        character += 1

    # Turning matrix into string
    final_text = ""
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        for column in range(len(cipher_key)):
            final_text += output_matrix[row][column]
    final_text = final_text.rstrip()
    
    return final_text


while True:  # User Interface and selection
    option = input("""This is a transposition cipher. Please select what you would like to do:
    1. Encrypt
    2. Decrypt
    3. Quit
    """)

    if option == '3':  # User quits program
        break

    elif option == '1' or option == '2':  # Option 1 or 2 is selected
        path_to_input_file = input("Please enter the path to the file you would like to work on: ")
        with open(path_to_input_file, 'r') as file:
            input_text = file.read()
        cipher_key = input("Please enter your key: ")
        cipher_key_alphabet_order = sorted(range(len(cipher_key)), key=lambda character: cipher_key[character])
        
        # Adjusting input_text to the appropriate length and building an empty matrix
        number_of_rows = len(input_text) // len(cipher_key) # High ceiling if divisible 
        if len(input_text) % len(cipher_key) != 0:
            number_of_rows = ( len(input_text) + len(cipher_key) - 1 ) // len(cipher_key) # High ceiling if not divisible
            input_text += " " * ( number_of_rows * len(cipher_key) - len(input_text) )
            
        input_matrix = [[" " for column in range(len(cipher_key))] for row in range(number_of_rows)]
        output_matrix = [[" " for column in range(len(cipher_key))] for row in range(number_of_rows)]
        
        output_text = encrypt(input_text, cipher_key, number_of_rows, input_matrix, output_matrix, cipher_key_alphabet_order) if option == '1' else decrypt(input_text, cipher_key, number_of_rows, input_matrix, output_matrix, cipher_key_alphabet_order)
        with open(path_to_input_file, 'w') as file:
            file = file.write(output_text)
        print("""Transposition successful. Your file is ready.
        """)
    else:  # Invalid input from user
        print("""Invalid input. Please try again.
        """)


[" " for column in range(0, number_of_columns)] can be simplified to just [" "] * number_of_columns

Thanks, I'm new to python have not yet learned all the syntaxes. My only eperience with code was with c# when I was 16 and there you always had to assign start and end value in for loops. I quit school after that and never went back to coding untill now.

If you want to uncover the plaintext of a message that has been encrypted using transposed letters and sorted by alphabetically ordered columns then you'll have accomplish two areparts to make this work.
Here's what you'll need:

Prepare a form of encryption table using the rotated letters method (a classic example might be ROT13).

Choose a key from this list that is as easy to remember as possible.

Find the corresponding number (i.e., 0 to 25) for each letter in your plaintext.


For example, the letter 'A' is 0; 'Z' is 1; and 'F' is 5.
Use this method with other transposition cipher algorithms and alphabetical sortings.
def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    # Calculate dimensions
    num_columns = len(key)
    num_rows = -(-len(ciphertext) // num_columns)  # Ceiling division
    
    # Create the matrix from the ciphertext
    matrix = [[''] * num_columns for _ in range(num_rows)]
    index = 0
    for col in range(num_columns):
        for row in range(num_rows):
            if index < len(ciphertext):
                matrix[row][col] = ciphertext[index]
                index += 1
    
    # Generate the sorted order of the key
    sorted_order = sorted(range(len(key)), key=lambda k: key[k])
    
    # Create a mapping from sorted position to original position
    position_mapping = {sorted_pos: original_pos for original_pos, sorted_pos in enumerate(sorted_order)}
    
    # Rearrange the columns
    decrypted_matrix = [[''] * num_columns for _ in range(num_rows)]
    for col in range(num_columns):
        original_col = position_mapping[col]
        for row in range(num_rows):
            decrypted_matrix[row][original_col] = matrix[row][col]
    
    # Read the decrypted text
    plaintext = ''.join(''.join(row) for row in decrypted_matrix)
    return plaintext.rstrip()  # Remove any trailing spaces

# Example usage
ciphertext = "LO_FGAISRA_BMIIN_D"
key = "BANNER"
decrypted_text = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
print(decrypted_text)  # Output: FLAMINGO_IS_A_BIRD

